# Clipped Image has wrong shape in Google Earth Engine

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

In the Google Earth Engine Python API, when I select a polygon around a high latitude region and use `.clip()` to clip an image to the polygon (in my example I used MODIS landcover data, but it seems to be happening to every other dataset I look at) the result is an image with curved top and bottom edges. How do I resolve this so the image is clipped to the boundaries of the polygon? An example of the code and a resulting image are below, with the polygon also highlighted:

```
boundaries = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[4.1103796959,75.8666447688],
                               [36.5792269069,75.8666447688],
                               [36.5792269069,81.1817566002],
                               [4.1103796959,81.1817566002],
                               [4.1103796959,75.8666447688]]])

clipped_img = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1')\
                    .select('LC_Type1')\
                    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2010,2010,'year'))\
                    .first()\
                    .clip(boundaries)
```

[image: Incorrectly clipped image1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `ee.Geometry.Polygon(coordinates)` with no other options gives you a polygon with *geodesic* edges. Geodesic edges are defined to take the shortest path on the globe between two points. When viewed in a projection where horizontal lines are lines of latitude, they will appear to be concave towards the equator.

The clipping is accurate to this definition, but your polygon visualization seems to be failing to account for that, drawing straight *projected* lines instead.

If you want projected lines, you must specify that in the definition of the polygon:

```
boundaries = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[[4.1103796959,75.8666447688],
    [36.5792269069,75.8666447688],
    [36.5792269069,81.1817566002],
    [4.1103796959,81.1817566002],
    [4.1103796959,75.8666447688]]],
  None,         # projection (defaults to 'EPSG:4326' WGS 84 degrees lon/lat, i.e. what you have now)
  False)        # non-geodesic
```

[Demo of both types in the Earth Engine Code Editor](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8e935207831ac02901899c2b529ceae5)

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful!